# Numpy generation of subsets of global array based on mask

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, mask

I am interested in generating a list (or np.array) of np.arrays from a global 2D array, based on a matching boolean mask using numpy, for a particular axis. I was wondering if np.ma.mask() or similar could be employed...

An example is probably better:

```
number= 10
x = np.linspace(0,number,num=number+1,dtype=int)
B = np.vstack((x%3==0, x%2==0, x%1==0))
X = np.vstack((x//3, x//2, x-1))

list_ = []
for i in range(1,number+1):
    pointer = X[:,i][B[:,i]]
    list_.append(pointer)

print(list_)
[array([0]), array([1, 1]), array([1, 2]), array([2, 3]), array([4]), array([2, 3, 5]), array([6]), array([4, 7]), array([3, 8]), array([5, 9])]
```

In the for-loop, I am basically extracting the values on axis=1 in the 2D array X, based on the boolean mask B. I achieve this by iterating over axis=0 and selecting X[:,i][B[:,i]]. I am wondering whether it is possible to do this without the loop, since the range can be very big, and do it entirely in numpy, perhaps using a where statement on np.ma.array(X,mask=B)?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I would follow to solve the case in a vectorized manner -

1. Use `boolean indexing` to select the valid elements from `X`.
2. Get the indices at which we see column indices shifting for the input mask. This would be achieved after transposing the mask, using `np.where` and selecting the first input arg.
3. Finally, with those indices, split the valid elements array obtained in step 1.

The implementation would look like this -

```
cut_idx = np.unique(np.where(B[:,1:].T)[0],return_index=True)[1]
out_list_ = np.split(X[:,1:].T[B[:,1:].T],cut_idx[1:])
```